# Does a constant function, $f(x)=a$, have the Intermediate Value Property?

Tags: calculus

[Taken from p. 51 of Advanced Calculus: An Introduction to Linear Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D5v8.jpg)

I'm really confused about this. A constant function is continuous everywhere, but there are no possible values for $k$ strictly in between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ since $f(a)=f(b)$. Is the "with $a < b$ and for all $k$ strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$" part true vacuously or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: This is vacuously true.

Comment: Yeah it’s vacuously true because for all $a<b$, there aren’t any $k$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, so any property about these non-existent $k$ will be true.

Answer (score 1):

It is vacuously true once there is no $k$ **strictly** between $f(b)$ and $f(a)$, since $f(b)=f(a)$ for all $a,b \in I$.

Comment: Okay, so it was what I thought. Thanks for clearing that up!